# Plotly chart sizes correctly only when minimizing-maximizing screen

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I will try explain this best I can. I have rendered a chart in plotly to HTML and everything looks fine. I have set the layout autosize correctly `autosize: true` using js. However, when the page loads the chart only takes up half the `<div>`. When I minimize the screen to a mobile view and then maximize it again, the chart then is displayed correctly, taking up the full width of the div. I cannot figure out why, obviously I want the chart to display full width. See below before and after:

Screenshot of div when page is freshly loaded.

[image]

After minimizing and then maximizing screen - you can see it takes up the full width as desired

[image]

Current config:

```
var layout= {
            xaxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'X Axis Title',
                },
                automargin: true
            },
            yaxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Y Axis Title',
                },
                automargin: true
            },
            autosize: true,
            paper_bgcolor: "#00000000",
            plot_bgcolor: "#00000000"
        }
        
        Plotly.newPlot('chart_div', data, layout, {responsive: true});
```